# What is the difference between service, directive and module?

Tags: angularjs

I have been reading a lot of docs, and I'm getting more and more confused.
I basically can't figure out the difference between a

- service
- directive
- module

I see a lot of custom components. Sometimes they're using directives, sometimes services. It always starts with a module. Can someone explain with an example what the difference is between these three types?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Think of a module as being a place to wire up a number of other things, such as directives, services, constants etc. Modules can be injected into other modules giving you a high level of reuse.

When writing an angular app, you would have a top-level module which is your application code (without templates).

Services are mainly a way to communicate between controllers, but you can inject one service into another. Services are often used as a way to get to your data stores and people will wrap the angular APIs, such as ngResource. This technique is useful since it makes testing (particularly mocking) quite easy. You can have services for doing other things like authentication, logging etc.

Directives are used for creating widgets or wrapping existing things like jquery plugins. Wrapping existing plugins can be a challenge and the reason you would do this is to establish a two-way data binding between the plugins and angular. If you don't need two-way data binding then you don't need to wrap them.

A directive is also a place for doing DOM manipulation, catching DOM-events etc. You should not be doing DOM-related stuff in controllers or services. Creating directives can get pretty complex. IMHO, I recommend first looking at API for something that can do what you are looking for OR ask Angular's Google Group for advice.

Answer (score 240):

From my own [personal notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12w4NKsix-kaZFu5Chha4HnIHzs5jhNiP2AcRoaVThyU/edit) (mostly snippets from the docs, google group posts, and SO posts):

**Modules**

- provide a way to namespace/group services, directives, filters, configuration information and initialization code
- help avoid global variables
- are used to configure the $injector, allowing the things defined by the module (or the whole module itself) to be injected elsewhere  (Dependency Injection stuff)
- Angular modules are not related to CommonJS or Require.js.  As opposed to AMD or Require.js modules, Angular modules don't try to solve the problem of script load ordering or lazy script fetching. These goals are orthogonal and both module systems can live side by side and fulfill their goals (so the docs claim).

**Services**

- are singletons, so there is only one instance of each service you define. As singletons, they are not affected by scopes, and hence can be accessed by (shared with) multiple views/controllers/directives/other services
- You can (and probably should) create custom services when

  - two or more things need access to the same data (don't use root scope) or you just want to neatly encapsulate your data
  - you want to encapsulate interactions with, say, a web server (extend $resource or $http in your service)
- Built-in services start with '$'.
- To use a service, dependency injection is required on the dependent (e.g., on the controller, or another service, or a directive).

**Directives** (some of the items below say essentially the same thing, but I've found that sometimes a slightly different wording helps a lot)

- are responsible for updating the DOM when the state of the model changes
- extend HTML vocabulary = teach HTML new tricks. 
  Angular comes with a built in set of directives (e.g., ng-* stuff) which are useful for building web applications but you can add your own such that HTML can be turned into a declarative Domain Specific Language (DSL).  E.g., the <tabs> and <pane> elements on the Angular home page demo "Creating Components".

  - Non-obvious built-in directives (because they don't start with "ng"): a, form, input, script, select, textarea.  Under Angular, these all do more than normal!
- Directives allow you to "componentize HTML".  Directives are often better than ng-include.  E.g., when you start writing lots of HTML with mainly data-binding, refactor that HTML into (reusable) directives.
- The Angular compiler allows you to attach behavior to any HTML element or attribute and even create new HTML elements or attributes with custom behavior. Angular calls these behavior extensions *directives*.

  - When you boil it all down, a directive is just a function which executes when the Angular compiler encounters it in the DOM.
- A directive is a behavior or DOM transformation which is triggered by a presence of an attribute, an element name, a class name, or a name in a comment.  Directive is a behavior which should be triggered when specific HTML constructs are encountered in the (HTML) compilation process. The directives can be placed in element names, attributes, class names, as well as comments.

  - Most directives are restricted to attribute only.  E.g., DoubleClick only uses custom attribute directives.
- see also [What is an angularjs directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875466/what-is-an-angularjs-directive/13898058#13898058)

Define and group Angular things (dependency injection stuff) in modules.
Share data and wrap web server interaction in services.
Extend HTML and do DOM manipulation in directives.
And make Controllers as "thin" as possible.

Comment: @Mark Rajcok - Nice answer, I already gave you +1, but it would be great to clarify more item 3 under Modules, i.e. "configure the $injector" People understand injecting services but how does this relate to modules?

Comment: @LeeWhitney, see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#dependencies: "Modules can list other modules as their dependencies. Depending on a module implies that required module needs to be loaded before the requiring module is loaded. In other words the configuration blocks of the required modules execute before the configuration blocks of the requiring module."

Comment: @MarkRajcok Link is now broken

Answer (score 0):

Take it with a pinch of salt, I am new to AngularJs (old version), but super good at React. So...

Angular is made up of 3 things:

1. Module
2. Directives / Components
3. Services

---

Module:

- general wrapper around your whole app (usually there is only one) - i.e. goes into the <body ng-app='yourModuleNameAkaMainWrapperComponentWithoutHtmlTemplate>
- it will create $rootScope that is avaialble to your whole app
- You can think of it as MAIN COMPONENT that has controller (i.e. $rootScope but does NOT have an HTML template)
- is Module technically a Directive / Component = YES IT IS... module is just syntax jargon.
- In otherwords if you see a Module, assume it is a Component / Directive WITHOUT html template that is used as an app wrapper (i.e. goes inside ng-app div).

Directive / Components:

- your building blocks
- they are made up of 2 things: Controller (i.e. JavaScript code) and Template (i.e. HTML code)
- Component vs Directive??? = tomAto / tomatO ... same thing... docs say that 'components are just watered down version of directives', but that is subjective, based on syntax and usage they are same thing.

Services:

- these are used for components to pass values between each other
- you can do it via Props (if they are related), if NOT, then use service

---

Thats about it.

Everything else is just syntax jargon:
e.g.

- expressions = basically way to bind values from controller to html in a component
- pipes = basically build in 'formatting tools' like currency, etc.

---

ps: Techncially you can say that Angular is just made up of 2 things:

1. Components (module, directive, component - these are all same thing only labeled differently - the difference being is where they are used, so module is used at HIGHEST LEVEL and does NOT have an HTML template... while components / directives are everywhere else)
2. Services (aka long range props) - so if components can NOT pass props directly between themselfs OR they might create 'property drilling', you use a service.

That's about it!