# What is directive in Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a hard time understanding directives in AngularJS. The definition by AngularJS themselves is confusing at best:

`Directives are a way to teach HTML new tricks. During DOM compilation directives are matched against the HTML and executed. This allows directives to register behavior, or transform the DOM.`

Could someone explain directives in AngularJS in plain English commonly used in teaching programming. Something like: `directives are funcions/objects that extends ...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an angularjs directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875466/what-is-an-angularjs-directive)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are a way to extend HTML, adding new elements and/or adding new attributes to existing elements.
From Angular's developer guide:

*A directive is a behavior or DOM transformation which is triggered by the presence of a custom attribute, element name, or a class name. A directive allows you to extend the HTML vocabulary in a declarative fashion.*

You can use them either for adding behavior to HTML, defining a *link* function that keeps bidirectional binding between variables belonging to scopes and DOM elements, or for dynamically manipulating DOM, defining a *compile* function that can modify or even generate new DOM elements and attributes.
Consider it a way of extending HTML and transforming it into a *Domain Specific Language*.

Comment: I see what you mean, but can you elaborate on how it makes HTML a domain specific language? I think it's domain is pretty much just the internet. Are you saying that with Angular it becomes more of a domain specific PROGRAMMING language as opposed to a markup language?

Answer (score 4):

Directives can be attributes, tags or even class names.

Once you write them in your HTML markup, it gets picked up by angular and acts the way you defined it.

It gives you the ability to define new custom HTML elements like  or , or new behavior attributes like

```
<div angry></div>
```

And whenever someone will click on that div he will get and alert with "I'm Angry".

You can basically do every extension you need in order to make your html as lean and understandable as possible. it all depends with how you define you directive.

Comment: There is no such thing as an _angular interpreter_, directives are parsed during the DOM parsing phase, their compile function is executed to transform DOM and after their link function is attached to scope and executed in the context of the browser event loop.

Comment: Angular's digest cycle is not the browser event loop, it just gets triggered by it. But you're right, and you're smarter and also more handsome... I'll remove the word "interpreter".

Comment: I'm neither smarter nor more handsome than you, I just wanted to remark that angular code is not interpreted because I thought that could be confusing to everyone reading. Anyway I apologize, I neither wanted to be offensive nor diminish your answer

Comment: I was just kidding.. just wanted to give a lighter version to the over complicated version of the docs, but wasn't 100% precise so my bad.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Directives are a combination of HTML template markup (i.e. attributes, elements and CSS class) and supporting the JavaScript code. The angularJs JavaScript code defines the html data and behavior of the html element.

AngularJs directive are use to extend the HTML vocabulary i.e they decorate the html elements with new behavior and help to manipulate html elements attributes in interesting way.

There are some built-in directives provided by AngularJS like as ng-app, ng-controller, ng-repeat, ng-model etc