# Does it make sense to use angular services with es6 modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Does it make sense to use angular-services when we use ES6 modules? For example we need a singleton module (`userService`) in our code and we can do like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('userService', function(){
    this.users = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
});

app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', 'userService', function($scope, userService){

    console.log(userService);

}]);
```

But we can define the service in separate file:

```
/* ./user-service.js */
export default users = ['John', 'James', 'Jake'];
```

, then make the code like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var userService = require('./user-service')    

app.controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope){

    console.log(userService);

}]);
```

and result will be absolutely the same as with services using. So why use angular services when we can use modules?

Comment: Here you don't use the service with dependency injection. Therefore you cannot mock and unittest your service and your controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: [Difference between service, directive and module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171778/difference-between-service-directive-and-module) =)

From my own [personal notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12w4NKsix-kaZFu5Chha4HnIHzs5jhNiP2AcRoaVThyU/edit) (mostly snippets from the docs, google group posts, and SO posts):

**Modules**

- provide a way to namespace/group services, directives, filters, configuration information and initialization code
- help avoid global variables
- are used to configure the $injector, allowing the things defined by the module (or the whole module itself) to be injected elsewhere  (Dependency Injection stuff)
- Angular modules are not related to CommonJS or Require.js.  As opposed to AMD or Require.js modules, Angular modules don't try to solve the problem of script load ordering or lazy script fetching. These goals are orthogonal and both module systems can live side by side and fulfill their goals (so the docs claim).

**Services**

- are singletons, so there is only one instance of each service you define. As singletons, they are not affected by scopes, and hence can be accessed by (shared with) multiple views/controllers/directives/other services
- You can (and probably should) create custom services when

  - two or more things need access to the same data (don't use root scope) or you just want to neatly encapsulate your data
  - you want to encapsulate interactions with, say, a web server (extend $resource or $http in your service)
- Built-in services start with '$'.
- To use a service, dependency injection is required on the dependent (e.g., on the controller, or another service, or a directive).

**Directives** (some of the items below say essentially the same thing, but I've found that sometimes a slightly different wording helps a lot)

- are responsible for updating the DOM when the state of the model changes
- extend HTML vocabulary = teach HTML new tricks. 
  Angular comes with a built in set of directives (e.g., ng-* stuff) which are useful for building web applications but you can add your own such that HTML can be turned into a declarative Domain Specific Language (DSL).  E.g., the <tabs> and <pane> elements on the Angular home page demo "Creating Components".

  - Non-obvious built-in directives (because they don't start with "ng"): a, form, input, script, select, textarea.  Under Angular, these all do more than normal!
- Directives allow you to "componentize HTML".  Directives are often better than ng-include.  E.g., when you start writing lots of HTML with mainly data-binding, refactor that HTML into (reusable) directives.
- The Angular compiler allows you to attach behavior to any HTML element or attribute and even create new HTML elements or attributes with custom behavior. Angular calls these behavior extensions *directives*.

  - When you boil it all down, a directive is just a function which executes when the Angular compiler encounters it in the DOM.
- A directive is a behavior or DOM transformation which is triggered by a presence of an attribute, an element name, a class name, or a name in a comment.  Directive is a behavior which should be triggered when specific HTML constructs are encountered in the (HTML) compilation process. The directives can be placed in element names, attributes, class names, as well as comments.

  - Most directives are restricted to attribute only.  E.g., DoubleClick only uses custom attribute directives.
- see also [What is an angularjs directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875466/what-is-an-angularjs-directive/13898058#13898058)

Define and group Angular things (dependency injection stuff) in modules.
Share data and wrap web server interaction in services.
Extend HTML and do DOM manipulation in directives.
And make Controllers as "thin" as possible.

Comment: All I would say is Modules is a poor reason and completely pointless IMHO. Dependency Injection on the other hand is useful

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It makes perfect sense.

Services implement a particular responsibility in your application, moving data between the data store and views.

Modules allow you to organize your code and separate sections with different responsibilities.

By putting each service into a module, you make it easier to browse and test your code. It's easy to find all of the code that implements a responsibility.