# Directive requiring a parent

Tags: angularjs, nested, angularjs-directive

I need a directive `ngTree` to get the controller of a parent `ngTree` element. Note that `require: "^ngTree"` would return the controller of current directive.

I know I could do a `ngTreeHelper` and put a div with it, between any two `ngTree` divs and `require: "^ngTreeHelper"` would work, but it's ugly. I wonder if there is something else I could do.

Comment: "Note that require: "^ngTree" would return the controller of current directive." - are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, besides actually trying it, I've seen it explained in another SO answer ["^require, with the addition of the caret, checks elements above directive in addition to the current element to try to find the other directive"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15691865/971193). The "in addition" is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a great built in way to do this. However [it is done in angular's form directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0/src/ng/directive/form.js#L39).

Swiping the code from there, this is what you need

```
var ngTreeController = $element.parent().controller('ngTree');
```

This is in the form directive's controller, but you should be able to do this from a link function too.

Comment: Thanks. To add to the answer, [controller(name) - retrieves the controller of the current element or its parent. By default retrieves controller associated with the ngController directive. If name is provided as camelCase directive name, then the controller for this directive will be retrieved (e.g. 'ngModel').](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)

Comment: Yep, and `.parent()` skips the current element, and so avoids taking the controller from the current `ngTree` as it would using `require`.