# What is the correct way to extend an AngularStrap directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I'm looking to extend an AngularStrap directive ([typeahead](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##typeaheads) in this case) to have more than the provided functionality. After some research, I'm thinking the best way is to wrap the typeahead directive with my own custom directive so that I can extend it.

I've followed all 3 suggestions found [here](http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/03/10/extending-an-existing-directive-in-angularjs/) for extending an Angular directive, but none of them seem to give me access to the typeahead controller and it's public functions.

Am I going about this the wrong way? What is the best way to extend the directives for custom functionality? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the approach similar to the 2nd way described [there](http://thaiat.github.io/blog/2014/03/10/extending-an-existing-directive-in-angularjs/).
The difference was to use 'require' to refer to the controller of the parent directive.

[How to require a controller in an angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of AngularStraps typeahead directive (*[Link](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js)*) you'll see that it has two parts, the provider; '$typeahead' and the directive 'bsTypeahead'. What I've found in the past is easiest with this library is to copy the 'bsTypeahead' directive, rename it to something else then modify it's code to do as I want. The $typeahead provider acts like the controller in this case and all other AngularStrap directives work the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, the best way is definitely to wrap the Angular Strap Directive in a Directive of your own. I've done this quite a bit with different Strap Directives. Secondly it's hard to say specifically what you need to do because you didn't name any specific goals. But if you look on the doc's for the Angular Strap project you'll notice various hints. In the case of typahead you have access to the $typeaheadProvider, also this is some what speculative on my part, but typeahead has a tooltip dependency so you may be able to use the $tooltip service to fiddle with typahead in your wrapper. Finally, the Angular Strap API for typeahead is pretty robust take another look at what is already available and you maybe able to accomplish what you want/need by working with what you've already got. I.E you can specify a custom template, or specify different prefix events which after taking another look at the docs myself seems to be an interface for interacting with the tooltip scope methods. I'm sorry this couldn't be more detailed on exactly what you need to do, but hopefully it will get you moving in the right direction.