# Angular Ui Bootsrap `dropdown` interfering with my directive require

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

In angular.js,  I use `require: "^helpme",` to inherit a directive's controller in my directive called `actionButton`...

```
angular.module("main.vips").directive("actionButton",
        function(LoadbalancerActionButtonService, VipActionButtonService,
                 NodeActionButtonService, StatusTrackService) {

            //get function arguements/services and make them
            //accessable for use
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            var services = {};
            args.map(function(service) {
                //not all services may return objects 
                if (Object(service) === service) {
                    services[Object.keys(service)] = service[Object.keys(
                        service)];
                }
            });

          return {
            templateUrl: "vips/directives/action_button.html",
            restrict: "AE",
            replace: true,
            require: "^helpme",
            transclude: false,
            scope: {
              label: "@?",
              icon: "@?",
              type: "@?",
              actions: "=?"
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
              return scope.actions = services[attrs.type];
              scope.$on('CREATE', function () {
                  console.log("create");
              });
            }
          }
});
```

With this template that uses Angular UI Bootstrap dropdown directive:

directives/action_button.html:

```
<div helpme class="btn-group action-button-icon" dropdown>
  ....
</div>
```

How directive is applied:

```
      <div id="{{vip.label}}" action-button type="vip" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" actions="actions.vips"
           class="pull-right"></div>
```

I get `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'helpme', required by directive 'dropdown', can't be found!`.

This makes no sense because because I am requiring `helpme` directive in `actionButton` directive.

Is this a bug? Any way I can require other directives in `actionButton` directive and still use Angular UI Bootstrap's `dropdown` in `actionButton` template?

Comment: Where are you defining your controller? and is it being properly included in your app?

Comment: For `require: "^helpme"`, I am defining the controller in the directive called `helpme`. But the dropdown directive should not have any concern of it when I require it in directive `actionButton`.

Comment: You're telling your directive that it needs a controller called `helpme`. The directive isn't defining it. The error message says it can't be found. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive

Comment: I am telling directive `actionButton` that is needs a controller called `helpme`, not `dropdown`. But it is `dropdown` that is complaining `Controller 'helpme', required by directive 'dropdown'`

Comment: Have you tried: `require: "?^helpme"`?