# handling interaction between angular directives for authentication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, for the sake of simplicity I have reduced my problem to the following:

**Directive 01 : handles authentication**

it is responsible for opening modals / windows and getting user authenticated.

```
angular
.module('app.directives')
.directive('requiresLogin', function(){       
     return {
         restrict : 'A',
         link : function() { //..}
     }
})
```

**Directive 02 : performs specific action**

```
angular
.module('app.directives')
.directive('like', function(){

     return {
         restrict : 'A',
         link : function() { //..}
     }
})
```

Both directive 01 and 02 bind click events.

I am bit confused about the design of two directives.

> I could make the second directive a child of the first one and get
>   communication between the directive, which to some extent makes sense
>   as the single responsibility of each directive is maintained under
>   this pattern. However all my future directives that would need
>   authentication will be children of the first directive.

**My Question is :**

How can prevent the second directive (actual action) based on the result of first "authenticating" directive ? Is there any other way of doing this without making a "parent-child" relation between them ?

Comment: Sorry, have you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only add the "action" directive and inject an auth service to it:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/dby686ab/

**Logic**

```
app.factory('user', function() {

    var roles = ['user'];

    return {
        hasRole: function(role) {

            return !role || roles.indexOf(role) > -1;
        }
    };
});

app.directive('like', function(user) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link    : function(scope, element, attrs) {

            element.on('click', function () {

                if (user.hasRole(attrs.authRole)) {

                    element.addClass('liked');
                    element.off('click');

                } else {

                    alert('Unauthorized.');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<a like="">Dogs</a>
<a like="" auth-role="user">Birds</a>
<a like="" auth-role="admin">Whales</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "require" definitly well explained in the following post :

[How to require a controller in an angularjs directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive)

In your context you could do:

```
.directive('requirelogin', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        controller: function() {
            var isLogged = false;

            this.isLogged = function() {
                if(isLogged) return isLogged; 
                alert("You are not logged!");
            };

            this.login = function(){
                isLogged = true;            
            };
        }
    };
})

.directive('like', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        require: '^requirelogin',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, loginCtrl) {
            scope.loginCtrl = loginCtrl;
            scope.sayILike = function(){
                if(scope.loginCtrl.isLogged()){
                    alert('I like');
                }
            };

            scope.login = function(){
                scope.loginCtrl.login();
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Working : http://jsfiddle.net/bennekrouf/nq9g33Lt/25/

Comment: ok... is there some explanation for this downvote ? sharing a controller between 2 directives is useful for saying that on depends from the other.

Comment: Could you develop your answer a bit more?