# Function of require in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have seen this require in custom directive.

```
require: '^create'
```

I can't understand this. Can you explain me require in angularjs?

Comment: Please read the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672709/how-to-require-a-controller-in-an-angularjs-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require`

- The require takes a string name (or array of strings) of the directive(s) to pass in.
- If an array is used, the injected argument will be an array in corresponding order.
- If no such directive can be found, or if the directive does not have a controller, then an error is raised (unless no link function is specified, in which case error checking is skipped).
- The name can be prefixed with:

(no prefix) - Locate the required controller on the current element. Throw an error if not found.

? - Attempt to locate the required controller or pass null to the link fn if not found.

^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents. Throw an error if not found.

^^ - Locate the required controller by searching the element's parents. Throw an error if not found.

?^ - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element and its parents or pass null to the link fn if not found.

?^^ - Attempt to locate the required controller by searching the element's parents, or pass null to the link fn if not found.

**Require a Controller**

If you want to share the same *instance* of a controller, then you use `require`.

`require` ensures the presence of another directive and then includes its controller as a parameter to the link function. So if you have two directives on one element, your directive can *require* the presence of the other directive and gain access to its controller methods. A common use case for this is to require `ngModel`.

`^require`, with the addition of the caret, checks elements above directive in addition to the current element to try to find the other directive. This allows you to create complex components where "sub-components" can communicate with the parent component through its controller to great effect. Examples could include tabs, where each pane can communicate with the overall tabs to handle switching; an accordion set could ensure only one is open at a time; etc.

In either event, you have to use the two directives together for this to work. `require` is a way of communicating between components.

Check out the Guide page of directives for more info http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive