# AngularJS Composite Components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a component that contains multiple child components. I'm creating a collection of directives that other developers on my team can use to create custom search forms. For example, they would create markup like:

```
<search-panel name="myCustomSearch">
    <search-field name="dates" type="dateRange"></search-field>
    <search-field name="categories" type="categorySelector" data="{{categories}}"></search-field>
</search-panel>
```

I have a search panel directive and several search field directives. The search panel acts as a container and the search fields each provides a specific type of field (date range, type ahead, category selector, etc). Each search field has a value property in it's scope and I am trying to figure out a way to have the parent search panel directive have a property in it's scope that contains a key, value collection of all of the child search fields.

I've got both directives rendering correctly, but I'm not sure how to either make the search-panel aware of/have access to all the child components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require in `search-field` directive a `search-panel` controller using `require:'^searchPanel'`

Then in link function you'll have a link to that controller, so those directives could add themselves into some array (I assuemm each search field has its isolated scope):

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, spCtrl) {
  spCtrl.fields.push({name: attrs.name, scope: scope});
}
```

(ofcourse, you could add not whole scope, but some object, then watch for changes and update value field of that object.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is to create a common controller between the two and link them up in the directive linking.

When you create a directive you can pass the controllers into the fourth parameter as such:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
  return {
    scope: true,
    link: function postLink( scope, element, attrs, ctrls ){
      //check ctrls for common link
    }
  }
}
```

An excellent example created in the angularui/bootstrap project is the **[Tabs Directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/tabs/tabs.js)** which has a common controller linking them up as an example on where to get started.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good stackoverflow answer here by Mark Rajcok:

[**AngularJS directive controllers requiring parent directive controllers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622863/angularjs-directive-controllers-requiring-parent-directive-controllers)

with a link to this very clear jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/StXFK/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div screen>
        <div component>
            <div widget>
                <button ng-click="widgetIt()">Woo Hoo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript is in the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of composite component (multiple transcluding directives) is based on the following idea:

- capture child component $transclude with one directive
- output this child component with another directive

Live demo http://nickholub.github.io/angular-composite-component/#/

Demo source code https://github.com/nickholub/angular-composite-component

Directive source code https://github.com/nickholub/angular-composite-component/blob/master/app/directive/angular-composite-component.js

```
<div cs-composite>
    <div cs-section="header">
        Composite Component Header
    </div>
    <div cs-section="footer">
        Composite Component Footer
        <div>Random Value: {{randomValue}}</div>
        <div>Percentage: {{percentage}}%</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Directive that captures content

```
.directive('csSection', function () {
    return {
      transclude: 'element',
      priority: 100,
      require: '^csComposite',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
        var directiveTransclude = {
          id: attrs.csSection,
          transclude: $transclude,
          element: element
        };

        ctrl.registerTransclude(directiveTransclude);
      }
    };
  })
```

Directive that outputs content

```
.directive('csTransclude', function () {
    return {
      transclude: true,
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var id = attrs.csTransclude;
        var directiveTransclude = scope.transcludes[id];
        if (directiveTransclude) {
          var selectedScope = scope.$new();
          directiveTransclude.transclude(selectedScope, function (clone) {
            element.append(clone);
          });
        }
      }
    };
  })
```