# AngularJS composite view with the same directive

Tags: angularjs, composite, directive

I have a question, about composite view in AngularJS, that is close to that one : [AngularJS Composite Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155232/angularjs-composite-components)

However, I would like to know if it is possible to have a directive that includes a list of the same directive, like this :

```
<mydirective name="thecontainer">
    <mydirective name="a"/>
    <mydirective name="b"/>
    <mydirective name="c"/>
</mydirective>
```

Thanks,

David.

**Edit**

Answering blesh, I will be more precise. I'm trying to display boxes (a simple square) that can have one or many boxes, themselves can have many boxes, etc.

Here is the directive

```
myApp.directive('box', function () {
return {
    restrict:'E',
    replace:true,
    templateUrl:"partials/box.html",
    scope: {
        name : '@'
    },
    link:function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        console.log("trying to log " + attrs.name);
    }
}
});
```

Here is the template :

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-header">
    <div>{{ name }}</div>
</div>
<div class="box-container">
    <!-- display other boxes here-->
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the interesting code in the view :

```
<box name="TOP" >
    <box name="SUB" >

    </box>
    <box name="SUB" >

    </box>
</box>
```

Obviously something is missing to tell the sub-boxes "hey please display in the right place into your parent and please, parent, adapt your size to the number of children you have"

David.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Think about nested ng-repeats.  This probably isn't a question for stackoverflow, since you haven't tried anything yet and don't have a specific problem.

Comment: yes, but I can't think of a base case with your example. your included directives, after compilation, will include more directives until the end of the days.

Comment: ok I have the answer, simply ng-transclude has to be included in the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was really simple, without ng-transclude, angular has no way to interpret correctly the content of the innner HTML tags. So the correct way to do it is to correct the template by adding a ng-transclude like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
        <div>{{ name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-container" ng-transclude>
        <!-- display other boxes here-->
    </div>
</div>
```