# Requiring a directive controller inside another directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using [Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). I want to add behavior to this component. According to this guide, [Extending Directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#extending-directives), I proposed some changes to this component. Changes can be view there: [GitHub PR #257](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/657).

So now, I am trying to *`require`* it inside my *extension* but Angular keep saying he can't find `datepicker` controller.

I read this thread on SO [AngularJS directive controllers requiring parent directive controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622863/angularjs-directive-controllers-requiring-parent-directive-controllers?s=ba6effd7-e39b-477b-9e5b-3ee8b3c6656f) in which the answer basically shows the same and it seems working, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/StXFK/).

I looked at the Angular version which is **1.0.3** in the Fiddle and I am using Angular **1.1.5**.

Did this change in latest Angular version or am I doing it wrong?

---

According to the comments, indeed, it still works with AngularJS 1.1.5. And ended finding what was messing up. As I wanted to extend the *core* functionalities, I wanted to edit the original template so I used the *templateUrl* and provided a path to a custom template, which worked when stacking the directives but the same when requiring directives mess the things up.

Do you know how I can override original template in this context?

Comment: It should work with 1.1.5 too.

Comment: I was curious about this, so I wired up a [new plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JQH2iS3tgiv84XVFiewe?p=preview). The child-date directive is successfully "require"ing the datepicker directive.  I added a `this.foo` into the datepicker directive to test.  Working ok.

Comment: You're both right. It should works for me too. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I previously succeeded to extend it by [stacking](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#stacking-directives) them and it works fine. Now, it doesn't work when I change the way to extend the directive… I'll keep searching what's wrong and see how to edit my question.