# AngularJS : Passing attribute value from one directive to transcluded one

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, transclusion

I have a situation where I have to create a container directive with some bells and whistles.. and then I have a list of directives that can be wrapped into that container directive.

Something like this:

```
<the-container foo="bell" bar="whistle">

    <some-directive></some-directive>

</the-container>


<the-container foo="potato" bar="tomato">

    <some-other-directive></some-other-directive>

</the-container>
```

Is there any way in which I can make `<some-directive>` and `<some-other-directive>` aware of the `foo` and/or `bar` attributes values of the directive they are transcluded in?

Basic theContainer directive

```
.directive("theContainer", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: "theContainer.html",
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.containerAttrs = {
                    foo: attrs.foo,
                    bar: attrs.bar
                };
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Let's presume that these two directives have different and unrelated function all together

someDirective

```
.directive("someDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: "someDirective.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {},
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            return function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // I need the value from theContainer foo and bar here
                // or anywhere in this directive for starters
                foo = 'bells';
                bar = 'whistles';
            };
        }
    }
});
```

someOtherDirective

```
.directive("someOtherDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: "someOtherDirective.html",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // I need the value from theContainer foo and bar here
            // or anywhere in this directive for starters
            foo = 'potato';
            bar = 'tomato';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Read more about AngularJS $scope inheritance. Maybe this post will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622863/angularjs-directive-controllers-requiring-parent-directive-controllers

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I think I read that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scopes in angular by default inherit from parent scope. Unfortunately, with angular default transclusion, there is no child/parent relationship between container and transcluded content.

You could try custom transclusion.

```
compile: function(element, attrs, linker) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.containerAttrs = {
          foo: attrs.foo,
          bar: attrs.bar
        };
        linker(scope, function(clone) { //bind scope anyway you want
          element.append(clone); // add to DOM anywhere you want
        });
      };
}
```

**Note**: remember to remove `ng-transclude` in your template when you do custom transclusion,

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YwsyeF1rq9u39E7TR9AV?p=preview)

Comment: This is great thank you! I can adjust it to what I need easily. I am aware that ng-transclude creates sibling scope,, I wasn't sure how to bypass that. This is perfect.