# How can I access a directive's ngModelController from another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I access a directive's `ngModelController` from another directive?

**The scenario**

I'm creating a type ahead widget, which is composed of a `typeAhead` directive and `autoCompletePopUp` directive. 
`AutoCompletePopUp` directive will interact with the `typeAhead` using `typeAhead's controller`.

But I don't know how to call `typeAhead's $setViewValue` from `autoCompletePopUp` when an item is selected.

Comment: These helped me a lot on this topic: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622863/angularjs-directive-controllers-requiring-parent-directive-controllers

Comment: @TrazeK Thank you, didn't know that nested directive share the same isolated scope.

Comment: No worries. A lot of us didn't know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add a function to the controller for `typeAhead` that calls $setViewValue on itself. In the context of `typeAhead's` controller you should have access to the scope. You can put the ngModelController for `typeAhead` on the scope if needed. Something like this:

```
angular.module("myModule").directive("typeAhead", function() {
   return {
      require: "ngModel",
      controller: function($scope) {
         this.setValue = function(value) {
            $scope.ngModelController.$setViewValue(value);
         };
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelController) {
         scope.ngModelController = ngModelController;
      },
   };
});

angular.module("myModule").directive("typeAhead", function() {
   return {
      require: "typeAhead",
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, typeAheadController) {
         scope.someAction = function(value) {
            typeAheadController.setValue(value);
         };
      },
   };
});
```

(protect against minification and move controllers into separate objects / files as desired; done inline here for convenience)

Comment: Thank you. How could I miss that?