# What is the best way to access parent directive scope from child directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

**AngularJS Module and Directives**

```
angular.module('tabApp', [])

.directive('tabPanel', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            isOpen: '='
        },
        template: '<div><div tab-content></div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            alert(scope.isOpen);
        }
    };
})

.directive('tabContent', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            isOpen: '='
        },
        template: '<div>Content</div>',
        link: function (scope) {
            alert(scope.isOpen);
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="tabApp">
    <div tab-panel is-open="true"></div>
</div>
```

I need the tabContent to access isOpen property in the tabPanel? What is the best and shortest way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be creating controllers for your directives / components, then you can use the `require` property and the `ctrls` argument. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to pass the `is-open` from the parent directive to child directive...

```
.directive('tabPanel', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            isOpen: '='
        },
        template: '<div><div tab-content is-open="isOpen"></div>',
        //...
    };
})
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zdz5sy1e/6/)

Comment: wow, i never thought the answer would be this simple, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

change child directive definition to

```
.directive('tabContent', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            isOpen: '='
        },
        template: '<div>Content</div>',
        link: function (scope, attr, element, tabApp) {
            alert(scope.isOpen);
        },
        require: '^tabApp'
    };
```

and then use link function to receive the tabApp, something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622863/angularjs-directive-controllers-requiring-parent-directive-controllers)

Comment: thanks, but this is not the answer that i want, because the <div tab-panel> can be placed in anywhere of the HTML. If the <div tab-panel> is in nested structure, the '^tabApp' wont work anymore.

Comment: so make it optional