# http.get in controller vs service : angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In the PhoneCat Tutorial in AngularJS site, it is suggested to replace http.get with our own custom service. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11
Besides making the code modular is there any other use of this ?
(Read somewhere that services are called just once, unlike controllers. Not sure about that though)

Comment: I just want to know what is the use of defining our own service when there is an inbuilt http.get. Can the service do something else ? IMHO answer to this would involve facts besides just opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in my opinion the reason using service as data besides its readability is that the service in injectable to other modules, but not the controller.

further reading:

[more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171778/difference-between-service-directive-and-module)