# Angular Directives VS Services

Tags: angularjs

I was just going through the code of a openlayers and angular directive **[HERE](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-openlayers-directive/tree/master/src)**. can anybody explain to me what is the most fundamental difference between services and directives ?

I understand directives better , my understanding is that directives able a programmer to add addition `ng` tags to the existing one and make HTML recognize stuff that just plain native HTML would't otherwise recognize. But what purpose does services serve ?

Thank you.

Comment: try google first, my first option was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171778/difference-between-service-directive-and-module

Comment: There is really no similarities as they serve completely different purposes

Comment: ok thanks floks , lemme go through the duplicate .

Comment: @Tenali_raman suggest you read the angular developer guide based on recent other questions